# Upload blob and acquire lease in one transaction

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Is it possible to upload to blob storage and acquire a lease on that blob within the same transaction.  This would be to avoid a potential race condition.

The following code does the above but as two distinct transactions:

```
blob.UploadText(String.Empty);
blob.AcquireLease(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), leaseId);
```

If another thread/process/instance had to acquire a lease on that blob between the above two transactions, then a `StorageException` (HTTP code 412) would be thrown.

This can be mitigated by catching such exceptions, as shown below, but without being able to perform the upload and lease acquisition in one transaction we cannot guarantee that the blob will be leased by this thread after upload.

```
blob.UploadText(String.Empty);

try
{
    blob.AcquireLease(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), leaseId);
}
catch (StorageException ex)
{
    if (ex.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode != 412)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe your scenario in more details especially `avoid a potential race condition` one?

Comment: @GauravMantri: I have updated my question. Let me know if this is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible today to upload and acquire lease in just one transaction.

Looking at your code above, can't you put the `blob.UploadText` in the same try/catch block? That way upload operation by 2nd thread will fail if the 1st thread has acquired the lease. Also because these operations happen sequentially and not in parallel, more than likely the thread which uploaded the blob will acquire the lease. You will need to try it out though.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't entirely clear.  Other thread or processes don't upload the blob.  They are only asking to lease it out if it exists.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, one process will upload the blob and then there are separate processes just waiting and anyone could acquire the lease. What you want is that only the process which uploads the blob acquires the lease. Am I correct? Is using queues a possibility?

Comment: Yes, you are spot on.  I would certainly prefer not to use queues, but I understand that there may be no other option.

Comment: I would agree with you. With queues things would become somewhat easier. You have a process which writes a message into the queue. All other processes will try to `Get` this message but only one will succeed. That process becomes the leader and then upload the blob and acquire the lease.

Comment: There's yet another crazy idea :). Will it be possible for you to assign a unique id to each process? Then instead of writing empty string, you can write this process id in the blob. Each process will read the blob contents and compare with its own id. If the id matches then that process will proceed with acquiring the lease.